# how to show only selected item from treeview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, treeview

I am working with a Wpf/XAML based application which has DataGrid with one of the DataGridColumn containing the TreeView control to let user select the item required.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Width="*" Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field" Width="*">

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <uControls:FieldTreeViewControl />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                            
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentField.FieldName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Field column in above code is the one which displays treeviewcontrol in the DataGrid cell by referencing the FieldTreeViewControl and it works perfectly.  The xaml code of FieldTreeViewControl is :

```
<UserControl>
.......
    <Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="MyUITreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsNodeExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsNodeSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />


            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <!--<TextBlock Text="-" Margin="3"/>-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldName}" Margin="3"/>
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Name="myChildMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Field" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFieldCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <!--<DataTemplate x:Key="EditTemplate">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding FieldName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>-->
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate     ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentPresenter.Style>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"   Value="{StaticResource NormalTemplate}"/>

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                     Binding="{Binding IsNodeSelected,
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                          FindAncestor,
                                     AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                          Value="True">

                                    </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentPresenter.Style>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Now when user completes selecting an item from treeview I want to collapse treeview to show only that selected item. Later when user wants to change his selection , then the treeview should be available again by clicking on that column/cell. Is that possible to do this in wpf/XAML ? I tried to follow the [link](http://deanchalk.com/wpf-treeview-selecteditem-two-way-binding-2/) but not able to implement it for my scenario.